# Looking for design advice for custom electronic lock

Tags: circuit-design, raspberry-pi, electronic-load

I'm building a door lock that will be controlled by a Raspberry Pi Zero W.

Here's a link to the lock I'm using: [Electronic Cabinet Lock With Status Reporting (MA1208S-T)](http://www.eboxlock.com/Products/1313.htm)

From what I understand, this lock will basically have three states:

- Always unlocked, which requires a constant 6 V to keep the log disengaged.
- Locked, which requires no power.
- And a quick unlock, which requires 12 V to pop the lock (it gets very hot if I'm always pumping 12 V into it to keep it unlocked).

Here's a picture of what I have working:

[image: A working prototype]

- I'm using a 12 V adapter to power everything.
- The pi uses a 12 V to 5 V converter cable.
- I'm using two relays and two step-downs in order to control the voltages

My question is, is there a single component I can use that would replace the relays and step downs? Like something I can control with the Pi? I feel like I over complicated this and I'm hoping someone can give me better direction.

Comment: This isn't an answer, but some info: That lock is rated for intermittent use only. It should only be powered for 30 seconds at a time.

Comment: OP seems to be using 6 V to maintain the lock open.  This would give 1/4 power.

Comment: Correct I'm just just pumping 6 V into it to keep the lock open.

Comment: I gather you've tested the unit experimentally in order to find that \$6\:\text{V}\$ will hold it open. (I can't seem to find that specification on the web link you provided.) (1) Is that correct? (2) Are sure this will work each and every time you buy another one of those locks? (3) Do you believe the unit will have a "long life" if operated at \$6\:\text{V}\$, as the web site don't specify ***any*** continuously-open state as part of their guarantee of lifetime usage. (4) A circuit using the solenoid itself in pulsed saw mode to keep it open without needing a separate supply may be possible.

Comment: @jonk (1) Correct. (2) I've tested 20+ of these locks and they've all worked the same way.  (3) I have spoken with the manufacturer about this and they believe that using the device in this manner will not significantly decrease its life span.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Website says nothing about rating for holding it open, but if it's a solenoid that has the moving core seating against the stationary when energized it won't take a lot of current to keep it there (since the magnetic circuit's reluctance drops a lot unless there's still an intentional airgap at full travel).

You could just PWM a single FET to drive the solenoid, it likely only takes a 50-100ms pulse at full current to move the mechanism, then you can drop the duty down to something low to keep the current at a value that'll hold the solenoid seated. During the off period the current circulates through the freewheel diode, the decay is usually quite slow, so the PWM frequency won't need to be more than a few hundred Hz. No need for the step-down.

[image]